# change calling screen in ios replace with my application screen

Tags: ios, iphone, callkit

I designed an application screen for incoming and outgoing calls, so now the issue is that I want to show my screens on while I get an incoming and outgoing call on the device so how can I do that.is that's possible so tell me how?

Comment: CallKit is designed to provide the ability to display the native call screen when a incoming call notification for you app is detected, the OS provides no means for you to provide your own call screen or replace the native call screen - that's not what call kit is designed for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is not possible.**
You can not replace core features of iOS with your own app.
As [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) stated in his comment, CallKit allows you to use iOS call screen in your app. Not the other way around.

Comment: Yes, exactly this. And this is why apps that claim to do this are either totally fake or they offer a sort-of custom VoIP system with abnormally high rates and a calling system which doesn't properly implement CallKit.

Answer (score 0):

**CallKit** : Display the system-calling UI for your app's VoIP services, and coordinate your calling services with other apps and the system.

If you are using CallKit, its impossible so far to customize it or replace it.

You can do it, if your App has its own feature of Calling, say Many apps has WebRTC solutions or other VoIP Solutions.

Comment: "You can do it, if your App has its own feature of Calling, say Many apps has WebRTC solutions or other VoIP Solutions." Could you please comment a bit more on what you mean by this

Comment: means View inside App which shows as ringer as a call event is triggered or push tapped to open app to see call.